# Cannot increment value-initialized map/set iterator

Tags: c++, stdmap

I'm trying to increment key of nodes after the index j in a map, but I got some error while incrementing the iterator to the next node, here's my code :

```
typedef map<int, string> My_map;    
My_map my_map;
my_map[0] = "la base";
my_map[1] = "le premier";

int j = 1;

My_map::reverse_iterator first_it(my_map.rbegin());
first_it++;
My_map::reverse_iterator last_it(make_reverse_iterator(next(my_map.begin(), j - 1)));

for (My_map::reverse_iterator it = first_it ; it != last_it ; it++) {
    auto handle = my_map.extract(it.base());
    handle.key()++;
    my_map.insert(move(handle));
}
```

I know that a map cannot have duplicate keys, so I started incrementing from the last one to the j-th one. But the `it++` does not work. Is it different from when I used `first_it++;` ?

Comment: After `m_map.extract(it)`, any iterator to that element will be invalid.  You must replace `it` with an iterator based off the one returned by `insert`.  Otherwise `it++` will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Side-note: For performance, both of your `iterator++` uses should be changed to `++iterator`; the latter cheaply increments in place, returning a reference to the now-modified object, while the former must make a more expensive copy, increment in place, and return the copy (which must then be destroyed). As a rule, in C++, get in the habit of using pre-increment any time you don't *need* the behavior of post-increment.

Comment: Can you specify problem code should solve with more details. More complex example would be nice too. Also specify what is exact error you are seeing since I'm unable to reproduce problem: https://godbolt.org/z/fEbhMfzGe (what compiler version and its flags). Invalidation of iterator is a problem here, but I see possible other problems and I'm not sure if you are aware of it or you just added `first_it++;` by try and errors.

Comment: You can use test case to clearly specify your problem: https://godbolt.org/z/PcxabEEzv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract) for `std::map::extract` it mentions the side-effects:

> Extracting a node invalidates only the iterators to the extracted element. Pointers and references to the extracted element remain valid, but cannot be used while element is owned by a node handle: they become usable if the element is inserted into a container.

As you can see, all the iterators are find *except* for the ones you care about.  Because `it` is an iterator to the extracted element, it is now invalid.  Subsequent attempts to use it (with `it++` to advance the loop iteration) leads to undefined behavior.

What you can do is use the iterator returned by `std::map::insert`:

```
auto result = my_map.insert(move(handle));
it = make_reverse_iterator(result.position);
```

Comment: that's the answer, except that `std::map::insert` does not have a membre named first. Instead I used `it = make_reverse_iterator(result.position);`

Comment: Ahh whoops yes, that version returns `insert_return_type`.  Thanks for correcting.  I will edit that in.

Answer (score 0):

As [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71675252/cannot-increment-value-initialized-map-set-iterator#comment126672562_71675252) by @paddy, after calling `.extract()` method and doing `.insert()` again all your iterators are invalidated hence you can't run modifying loop any further.

I suggest following solution which is valid and faster. Into separate [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) copy all elements starting from `j`-th position. Delete them in map. Modify them in vector the way you like, for example by adding `+1` to all keys. Insert them all back at once by `.insert(begin, end)` method of a map. Clear vector of copied elements.

All suggested is implemented in below code snippet:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/1a377o5rf)

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::string> m;
    m[0] = "la base";
    m[1] = "le premier";

    int j = 1;

    auto const j_it = std::next(m.begin(), j);
    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> vcopy(j_it, m.end());
    m.erase(j_it, m.end());
    for (auto & [k, v]: vcopy)
        ++k;
    m.insert(vcopy.begin(), vcopy.end());
    vcopy.clear();

    // Show map
    for (auto const & [k, v]: m)
        std::cout << k << ": " << v << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0: la base
2: le premier
```